# RestSharp serialization to JSON, object is not using SerializeAs attribute as expected

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, rest, restsharp

I am using **RestSharp** (version 104.4 via NuGet) to make calls to a Rest Web Service. I have designed a set of objects (POCO) which matches resources exposed in the API. However, my objects property names does not match those expected by the Rest Service when posting data, so I would like to "transform" them when I make a request to the Rest service to make them match match. I read that adding `SerializeAs` attribute (with a Name specified) on my POCO's property will make them serialize correctly, but it won't.

**My POCO**

```
Imports RestSharp.Serializers

<Serializable(), SerializeAs(Name:="ApiMember")>
Public Class ApiMember
    <SerializeAs(Name:="id")>
    Public Property Id As Integer?

    <SerializeAs(Name:="email")>
    Public Property EmailAddress As String

    <SerializeAs(Name:="firstname")>
    Public Property Firstname As String

    <SerializeAs(Name:="lastname")>
    Public Property Lastname As String
End Class
```

**My Call to the API**

```
Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
Dim member As ApiMember = new ApiMember()

member.EmailAddress = "me@example.com"

request.Resource = "members"
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.AddBody(member)

Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient()
client.BaseUrl = "http://url.com"
client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password")
client.Execute(Of ApiGenericResponse)(request)
```

**What ends up being posted**

```
{"Id":null,"EmailAddress":"me@example.com","Firstname":null,"Lastname":null}
```

Notice the name of the properties does not match thoses I specified in `SerializeAs` (uppercases, name of EmailAddress)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I've stumbled across the very same problem - how did you solve this?

Comment: If you feel one of these answers helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: @marc_s I did not actually solved it, I was experimenting with RestSharp at that time, and I ended up either not using those "renamed" properties or just renaming my POCO properties to match those of the REST API.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is for @MaxiWheat and anyone else interested in how to use **JSON.NET** as the JSON serializer in a RestSharp request. Basically, I used the approach described in [this blog post by Patrick Riley](http://patrickrileyblogs.blogspot.com/2014/02/restsharp-using-jsonnet-serializer.html):

```c#
// create the request
var request = new RestRequest(yourUrlHere, Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

// attach the JSON.NET serializer for RestSharp
restRequest.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpJsonNetSerializer();
```

and the `RestSharpJsonNetSerializer` is an implementation (less than 100 lines of code) from the JSON.NET guys (John Sheehan) that [can be found on their Github pages](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs)

With this setup, my problems went away and I was able to have a proper DTO with nice CamelCase properties, while the serialized JSON uses them in all "lowercase".

Comment: But it doesn't work for deserializing. How can I get such behaviour with response data?

Comment: @Neshta - Guessing by now you found the answer, but if not, you can override the default IDeserializer using RestClient.AddHandler with your own implementation (similar to marc_s' answer.)  This blog has a sample implementation of an ISerializer and IDeserializer for Newtonsoft.JSON:  http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/

Comment: Note: Patrick's blog post calls the class "RestSharpJsonNetSerializer", while the link to the file within the repo has the class name as "JsonSerializer". That'll be a little speed bump if you copy and paste without paying attention. Ask me how I know...

Answer (score 19):

I came across this issue, and solved this a slightly different way than above, wanted to note it here.

We have a `factory` class that builds all of our requests. Looks like the following

```
public IRestRequest CreatePutRequest<TBody>(string resource, TBody body)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(resource)
    {
        Method = Method.PUT,
    };

    request.AddParameter("application/json", Serialize(body), ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return request;
}
```

Rather than use the `AddJsonBody` and `AddBody` methods against the request, both of which cause serialisation, I used `AddParameter` which will add the object you pass in without serialisation. I created a method called `Serialise`, which uses `JSON.net` to serialise our class.

```
private object Serialize<T>(T item)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
}
```

This then allows us to use `JSON.net`'s `JsonProperty` annotation above your propertys. Here is an example -

```
public class Example
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updated")]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In RestSharp 104.4, the default `JsonSerializer` doesn't use the `[SerializeAs]` attribute, as seen by reviewing the [source code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/3586cf8fbabcfa9ca39938967c98689d610503a6/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs) (note this code is from v104.4 as indicated in the question, not the latest version).

One workaround to this is to create a custom serializer that uses the Json.NET `JsonSerializer` (a good example is [here](http://patrickrileyblogs.blogspot.com/2014/02/restsharp-using-jsonnet-serializer.html)) and then decorate your properties with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute, like so:

```
<JsonProperty("email")>
Public Property EmailAddress As String
```

Comment: And this is why link-only (or mostly link) answers are bad. Both links are dead, and there is no info on how to create a custom serializer.

Comment: Archived page for the expired link to the custom serializer: https://web.archive.org/web/20150804061449/http://blog.patrickmriley.net:80/2014/02/restsharp-using-jsonnet-serializer.html

Answer (score 6):

RestSharp uses [SimpleJson](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json). This library doesn't know or respect the `[SerializeAs]` attribute (which [is XML-only anyway](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/SerializeAsAttribute.cs)), it just [outputs the POCO's property name](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json/blob/master/src/SimpleJson/SimpleJson.cs#L1268), unless it's compiled with `#SIMPLE_JSON_DATACONTRACT` defined, then you can use the `[DataContract]` attribute to rename properties.

So your options seem to be to recompile the SimpleJson library with that define and decorate your properties with the `[DataContract(Name="lowercasepropertyname")]` attribute, or create a custom serializer that uses a JSON serializer that does respect other attributes as suggested in @Ryan's answer.

Comment: Thanks a heap - ended up plugging JSON.NET back into RestSharp and now it works. Why was JSON.NET removed as a dependency, if the "replacement" is so broken that everyone needs to plug JSON.NET back into RestSharp anyway!?!?!? .....

Comment: I don't know, I think a REST library could very well benefit from a full-fledged JSON library anyway...

Comment: @marc_s Can you post how you plugged JSON.NET back into RestSharp? I think it would have helped me when I was tinkering with it. It seemed a little complicated for me, I'm not that much experienced in .NET yet.

Comment: @MaxiWheat: posted a response with the details of how I did it

Comment: Just to clarify: use [DataContract] on class, and [DataMember(Name="...")] on members. Example: https://blog.udemy.com/json-serializer-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1):

You could use following method in the Client side. It is essentially using Newtonsoft deserializer instead of built-in RestSharp deserializer. Newtonsoft deserializer respects DataMember Name property or JsonProperty.

```
    private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request)
    {
        var response = _client.Execute(request);
        if (response.ErrorException != null)
            throw new Exception("Error:" + response.ErrorException);

        return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, typeof(T));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the default JSON serializer in RestSharp uses `System.Text.Json`, which is a part of .NET since .NET 6. Therefore, you can use the attribute `JsonPropertyName` to decorate the properties in your POCO/DTO class.

Here's an example of a DTO class:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class FacebookAuthResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; } = null!;
    [JsonPropertyName("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; } = null!;
    [JsonPropertyName("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
}
```

And here's an example of how to make a request:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0");
var request = new RestRequest("oauth/access_token", Method.Get);
request.AddParameter("client_id", _clientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", _clientSecret);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _redirectUri);
request.AddParameter("code", code);
var response = client.Execute<FacebookAuthResponse>(request);
```

Note that nothing more than the attribute `JsonPropertyName` has to be added to the properties in the DTO class.