# RestSharp - how to influence JSON serialization (naming)?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to talk to a REST service and I'm trying to call a `POST` method where I need to provide some data in the post body.

I have my model class all nicely set up something like this:

```
public class MyRequestClass
{
    public string ResellerId { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    ... other properties of no interest here ... 
}
```

and I'm using RestSharp in C# to call my REST service something like this:

```
RestClient _client = new RestClient(someUrl);

var restRequest = new RestRequest("/post-endpoint", Method.POST);
restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

restRequest.AddJsonBody(request);   // of type "MyRequestClass"

IRestResponse<MyResponse> response = _client.Execute<MyResponse>(restRequest);
```

Everything seemed to work fine - no exceptions are thrown. But the service responds with:

> We are experiencing problem in processing your request

When I looked at the request JSON that's being sent, I see that all the properties are in Capitalized spelling:

```
{ "ResellerId":"123","TransactionId":"456" }
```

and this is causing the issue - the service excepts them in all lowercase:

```
{ "resellerId":"123","transactionId":"456" }
```

So I tried to decorate my C# model class with attributes:

```
public class MyRequestClass
{
    [RestSharp.Serializers.SerializeAs(Name = "resellerId")]
    public string ResellerId { get; set; }

    [RestSharp.Serializers.SerializeAs(Name = "transactionId")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    ... other properties of no interest here ... 
}
```

but that didn't seem to change anything - the JSON request sill has the property names in a Capitalized spelling and thus the call fails.

How can I tell RestSharp to always use **lowercase** property names in the JSON generated from a C# model class?

Comment: @CodeCaster: yes, seems to be dealing with the same problem. However: if move your answer there, I won't be able to accept it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: this answer is outdated. Read the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633649/restsharp-serialization-to-json-object-is-not-using-serializeas-attribute-as-ex) shared by @marc_s. I wont remove this answer because it used to be helpful.

You can or you should add Json.NET to RestSharp.

There is a issue about this on the [github repo of RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/358).

Comment: Now, that RestSharp got rid of the Json.NET dependeny (as per Version 103 (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/readme.txt)), is this sill the way to go today?

Comment: @Marcel I don't know. Consider my answer as outdated