# Using RestSharp, how to include a fieldname like "$fieldname" in RestRequest.AddJsonBody()?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

Using RestSharp, I need to POST a body containing a json string that looks like this:

```
{
    "$a": "b",
    "c": "d"
}
```

In the past I've created RestSharp requests using code like this:

```
var request = new RestRequest("someApiEndPoint", RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.AddJsonBody(new
{
    a = "b",
    c = "d"
});
```

What's the best way to add a "$" to the "a" property in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an anonymous type, you could just as easily switch to using a dictionary:

```
var root = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"$a", "b" },
    {"c", "d" },
};
var request = new RestRequest("someApiEndPoint", RestSharp.Method.POST)
    .AddJsonBody(root);
```

If you were using an explicit type, you could check *[RestSharp serialization to JSON, object is not using SerializeAs attribute as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633649/3744182)* for options.