# Deserializing REST resource to generic object

Tags: c#, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I am writing a program to integrate data between our Student Record System and the Finance System. The SRS is a cloud based solution while the Finance system is on-prem. Data is to be extracted from the SRS using its RESTful API. I then plan to write the returned resources to a staging database for integration with the finance system. After a bit of research I decided to use RestSharp as a foundation for my solution.

Following the [Recommended Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) guide I have been able to get a solution that is successfully making requests and deserializing the response data into my classes. However I’ve hit a small speed bump and need a bit of help to get going again.

The SRS Rest API contains the resource PostalAddressOccupancy. According to the SRS API documentation it has following structure:

[image]

My problem is with the occupant property. This, as indicated by the mixed type, can be any one of a number other resource types (ie Student, Staff, Guardian etc).

I can easily represent this in my data model using generics. Eg

```
public class PostalAddressOccupancy<T>
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrespondenceAddress { get; set; }
    public T Occupant { get; set; }
    public PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public string PostalAddressType { get; set; }

    public static PostalAddressOccupancy<T> GetPostalAddressOccupancy(string id)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = "PostalAddressOccupancy/{Id}",
            RootElement = "postalAddressOccupancy"
        };

        request.AddParameter("Id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient("SRS API");
        return restApiClient.Execute<PostalAddressOccupancy<T>>(request);
    }

    public static List<PostalAddressOccupancy<T>> GetPostalAddressOccupancies()
    {
        List<PostalAddressOccupancy<T>> list = new List<PostalAddressOccupancy<T>>();

        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = "PostalAddressOccupancy",
            RootElement = "postalAddressOccupancies"
        };

        RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient("SRS API");

        foreach (var pao in restApiClient.Execute<List<PostalAddressOccupancy<T>>>(request))
        {
            list.Add(GetPostalAddressOccupancy(pao.Href.Split('/').Last()));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

My problem is how to get RestSharp to correctly understand which type of occupant is being returned in the response data. Using the GetPostalAddressOccupancies method above I get a list of objects with everything   correctly deserialized apart from the occupant. This is returned as a base object type with its properties contained as key/value pairs.

Do I need to decorate my class or generic property with some tags to help provide a hint to the RestSharp deserializers?

I've also noticed that resources include base properties (eg entityType). Thus an occupant type can be identified through this, but I am unsure how that may help.

Comment: What is `RestApiClient`?  It doesn't seem to be a part of [restsharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RestApiClient&type=).

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, RestSharp uses [`SimpleJson`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/SimpleJson.cs) for JSON serialization.  Unlike Json.NET this serializer doesn't have built-in support for polymorphic property deserialization, custom converters or surrogate replacement.

Thus what you're going to need to do is to parse your response into an intermediate object -- specifically [`JsonObject`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/SimpleJson.cs#L121) -- then identify the type of occupant based on the properties present, then deserialize to a final type.

Firstly, it's going to be much easier to extract a non-generic base class for `PostalAddressOccupancy<T>` like so:

```
public abstract class PostalAddressOccupancy
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrespondenceAddress { get; set; }
    public PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
    public string PostalAddressType { get; set; }

    public abstract object GetOccupant();
}

public class PostalAddressOccupancy<T> : PostalAddressOccupancy
{
    public T Occupant { get; set; }

    public override object GetOccupant()
    {
        return Occupant;
    }
}

public class PostalAddress
{
    // Or whatever.  Type was not included in the question.
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine you have a variety of occupant types including:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StaffId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize to a `PostalAddressOccupancy<T>` given a [`IRestResponse`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IRestResponse.cs) where `T` could be `Student` or `Staff` using the following method that looks at the property names actually present in the JSON and selects the appropriate final type:

```
using SimpleJson;
using RestSharp;

public static class PostalAddressOccupancyExtensions
{
    public static PostalAddressOccupancy DeserializePostalAddressOccupancy(this RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
    {
        var addressObj = (JsonObject)SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
        var type = PostalAddressOccupancyExtensions.InferPostalAddressOccupancyType(addressObj);
        return (PostalAddressOccupancy)SimpleJson.SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(response.Content, type);
    }

    static Type InferPostalAddressOccupancyType(JsonObject root)
    {
        var occupantObj = root["Occupant"];
        if (occupantObj is JsonObject)
        {
            var occupant = (JsonObject)occupantObj;
            // Add logic to recognize other cases as required.
            if (occupant.ContainsKey("StudentId"))
            {
                return typeof(PostalAddressOccupancy<Student>);
            }
            else if (occupant.ContainsKey("StaffId"))
            {
                return typeof(PostalAddressOccupancy<Staff>);
            }
        }
        // Or throw an exception, if you prefer.
        return typeof(PostalAddressOccupancy<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { occupantObj.GetType() });
    }
}
```

Notice that having a non-generic base type means that the return signature can be something other than `object`.  Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aLD0Zj).

Note that if you were willing to use [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) you would have additional options.  E.g. you could:

- Plug Json.NET into RestSharp as shown in *[Custom JSON Serializer and JSON Deserializer for RestSharp](https://www.bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/)* or *[RestSharp serialization to JSON, object is not using SerializeAs attribute as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633649/3744182)*;
- Then use a [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to select the correct polymorphic subtype for `PostalAddressOccupancy` as shown in e.g. *[JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33321698/3744182)* or *[Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will try it out over the next day or so